# How to: height of "|" depends on both sides

Tags: math-mode, formatting, height

I want that a vertical line depends on the height of the signs to its left and to its right:
i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{equation}
    \left. AAAA \right| BBBB
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The height of $\right|$ does only depend on the height of AAAA but not on the height of BBBB.
What can I do to let the height of "|" depend on both the height of AAAA and of BBBB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{equation}
    \left. AAAA \middle| BBBB\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```